# Copy all images in a directory to sub-directories in batches of 30

Tags: command-line, bash, python

All of my images are in a single folder which are in excess of 1.6K. I want to make a batch of 30 images from the folder, and copy that batch over to its respective separate folder. The names of these folders can be anything, like `folder1`, `folder2`, `fodler3`, and so on.

I have no idea how to approach the problem. I thought about writing a Python script to copy the files one by one and, as soon as the count reaches 30, change the folder. But I thought that maybe you guys have a better idea on how to do it with Bash.

Comment: For `bash` you can apply the same logic as you planned for your python script, nevertheless, not the fastest (OK for a single run, though). However some effort by yourself is appreciated. Also more details: Any sorting desired? Any sorting in the names?

Comment: No sorting is needed, cause i  only have to send them for processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this Bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
from="/path/to/parent"       # <--- replace this
to="/path/to/target"         # <--- replace this
i=1

until [ "$(ls -A "$from")" = "" ]; do
    mkdir "$to/folder$i"
    files=("$from"/*)
    for f in "${files[@]:0:30}"; do
        mv "$f" "$to/folder$i"
    done
    i=$((i + 1))
done
```

In the above script replace the path of the `from` variable with the absolute path to the directory containing your images and the path of the `to` variable with the absolute path to the directory you want to move your images in. The batches of 30 images will be moved in directories named as `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3`, etc.

Save the script as `batch_move.sh` (or any name you wish) and make it executable by running:

```
chmod u+x /path/to/batch_move.sh
```

Then you can run the script as:

```
/path/to/batch_move.sh
```

Note: Just to be on the safe side, copy a portion of your images in another directory and test the script on that first. If it works as intended, then run it for all your images.

Comment: OMG you're a savior , I had to create a seprate VM to test the script but it worked thanks a lot, I''ll soon post a Python version for the same

Comment: @KABOOM Glad that you find it useful! Looking forward to your Python version!

Answer (score 4):

Use `GNU` **`parallel`**:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
mkdir_mv(){ target=$1; shift; mkdir "$target"; mv -t "$target" "$@"; }
export -f mkdir_mv
parallel -n 30 -j1 mkdir_mv "folder{#}" {} ::: *
```

As a normal `mv` won't create directories, we define a function first, that does that. We need to export the function to make it work with `parallel`

You will run the `parallel` command from the folder with your pictures.

**Explanation**:

- `-n 30` use 30 arguments for each parallel run
- `-j 1` run only 1 process in parallel (= do *not* run in parallel)
- `{#}` the current run number
- `{}` 30 arguments for each run.
- `:::` argument separator.
- `*` The input files.

---

`parallel` can be installed with:

```
sudo apt install parallel
```

Comment: This seems like a good approach - you may find that it hits the `ARG_MAX` limit, but that could be overcome by using `printf '%s\0' * | parallel --null`. IIRC it's also permissible to execute a (suitably quoted) sequence of shell commands directly so you could avoid the function ex. `printf '%s\0' *.jpg | parallel --null -n 30 'mkdir -p folder{#} && cp -t folder{#} {}'`

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for-loop with increment by 30.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

source=/opt/files/old
target=/opt/files/new

cd "$source" # && touch {000..300}

eval a=($( \
    ls --quoting-style=shell-escape) \
)
for ((b=0; b<${#a[@]}; b+=30)); do
    mkdir -p "$target/folder$((++c))" && mv -t "$_" "${a[@]:$b:30}"
done
```