# Copying certain amount of files to multiple directory

Tags: command-line, bash, directory

I have 5000 files and 50 sub directories in one directory. I want to move each 100 files to each directory. Can anyone provide any suggestion how to do it? Thanks in advance.

```
file_count=$(ls ABC* | wc -l)    
echo $file_count    
i=1    
dir_count=$(( file_count / 100))    
echo $dir_count    
dir_count1=`expr $dir_count + 1 `    
while [ $i -lt $dir_count1 ]    
do    
  mkdir $i
  i=`expr $i + 1`    
done
```

This is how I have created the directories runtime and want to copy the files returned from the first line of the script to each directory. Each directory should have 100 files.

Comment: please read [ask] then [edit] your question with what you have tried so far with any error messages and your version of ubuntu.

Comment: I'd start with `ls | split -l 100` and use the resulting files as a base for further processing.

Comment: Related: [Copy all images in a directory to sub-directories in batches of 30](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301356/copy-all-images-in-a-directory-to-sub-directories-in-batches-of-30/1301452#1301452)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are likely more elegant ways to do this. But this works

```
files_per_dir=100
file_count=$(ls -1 ABC* | wc -l)
dir_count=$((file_count / files_per_dir))
echo $dir_count
dir_count1=$(expr $dir_count + 1)
echo $dir_count1

for idir in $(seq 1 ${dir_count1}) ; do
  file_list=$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep -v au_ | head -${files_per_dir} | tr '\r\n' ' ')
  echo $file_list
  mkdir $idir
  mv $file_list $idir
done
```

**Notes**:

1. I used `grep -v au_` in the pipe to avoid my bash script (named `au_...`) being moved. You might need a different string, or not need it at all.
2. The `seq` loop replaces your `while` loop.
3. `ls -1 ABC* | wc -l` can be replaced with `ls ABC* | wc -w`.

Comment: Thanks a lot...it worked perfectly! @sancho

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need some kind of "round robin" distribution of the files into the various new directories, I'd suggest making the target directories as-needed, something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob

nPer=100

files=( ABC* )

i=0; 
while (( i < ${#files[@]} )); do 
  if ! (( i % nPer )); then 
    newDir=dir$(( 1 + i/nPer ))
    echo mkdir -p "$newDir" || break
  fi
  echo mv -nt "$newDir" -- "${files[i]}"
  ((++i))
done
```

or POSIXly

```
#!/bin/sh

nPer=100

set -- ABC*

i=0;
while [ $# -gt 0 ] && [ -e "$1" ]; do
  if [ $((i % nPer)) -eq 0 ]; then
    newDir=dir$((1 + i/nPer))
    echo mkdir -p "$newDir" || break
  fi
  echo mv -nt "$newDir" -- "$1"
  shift
  i=$((i + 1))
done
```

Remove the `echo`s once you are happy that it is doing the right thing.

---

Testing with nPer=10 and a directory of 42 ABC* files (not a multiple of nPer, so that we can see what happens at the edge):

```
$ ls ABC*
ABC01  ABC04  ABC07  ABC10  ABC13  ABC16  ABC19  ABC22  ABC25  ABC28  ABC31  ABC34  ABC37  ABC40
ABC02  ABC05  ABC08  ABC11  ABC14  ABC17  ABC20  ABC23  ABC26  ABC29  ABC32  ABC35  ABC38  ABC41
ABC03  ABC06  ABC09  ABC12  ABC15  ABC18  ABC21  ABC24  ABC27  ABC30  ABC33  ABC36  ABC39  ABC42

$ ./myscript
$ ls
dir1  dir2  dir3  dir4  dir5  myscript
$
$ ls dir?
dir1:
ABC01  ABC02  ABC03  ABC04  ABC05  ABC06  ABC07  ABC08  ABC09  ABC10

dir2:
ABC11  ABC12  ABC13  ABC14  ABC15  ABC16  ABC17  ABC18  ABC19  ABC20

dir3:
ABC21  ABC22  ABC23  ABC24  ABC25  ABC26  ABC27  ABC28  ABC29  ABC30

dir4:
ABC31  ABC32  ABC33  ABC34  ABC35  ABC36  ABC37  ABC38  ABC39  ABC40

dir5:
ABC41  ABC42
```

Comment: Thanks mate! will try this one too! @steeldriver